# Antd form custom validator

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to create an antd form with custom validation.

The code is available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-violet-xgp2d?fontsize=14)

The problem with it is

1) I am not getting feedback below the field.

2) I am not able to submit the form.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`wrappedComponentRef`](https://ant.design/components/form/#Form.create(options)) because of your modal wrapping the `Form`.

```
class CustomizedForm extends React.Component { ... }

// use wrappedComponentRef
const EnhancedForm =  Form.create()(CustomizedForm);
<EnhancedForm wrappedComponentRef={(form) => this.form = form} />
this.form // => The instance of CustomizedForm
```

Check the next sandbox with a `Modal` wrapping a form.

```js
class CollectionsPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    visible: false,
  };

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: true });
  };

  handleCancel = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: false });
  };

  handleCreate = () => {
    const { form } = this.formRef.props;
    form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (err) {
        return;
      }

      console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      form.resetFields();
      this.setState({ visible: false });
    });
  };

  saveFormRef = formRef => {
    this.formRef = formRef;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>
          New Collection
        </Button>
        <CollectionCreateForm
          wrappedComponentRef={this.saveFormRef}
          visible={this.state.visible}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}
          onCreate={this.handleCreate}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit hungry-wildflower-vccgm]

Comment: You are not using the custom validator in your example which is where the error was :)

Comment: Its official example

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue. The error was that I was not calling the callback in the try block of the validator

```
turbinesValidator = (rule, value, callback) => {
    try {
        let output = Number(value)

        if ((output < 1) || (output > 40) || (!Number.isInteger(output))) {
          throw new Error('Turbines must be an integer between 1 to 40.');
        }

        callback() // << ---this 
    }

    catch (err) {
      callback(err);
    }
  }
```